# How to set multiple attribute sets' values to the same in Nix?

Tags: nix

I've got [the following code](https://gitlab.com/victor-engmark/root/-/blob/6dad3e693d77c6fd20be1881ae756ab77d4437e5/configuration.nix#L398-401):

```hs
extraGroups = {
  realtime.members = [ config.users.users.default.name ];
  wireshark.members = [ config.users.users.default.name ];
}
```

Ideally I'd simply shorten the inner part to one of the following:

```hs
realtime.members = wireshark.members = [ config.users.users.default.name ];
{realtime, wireshark}.members = [ config.users.users.default.name ];
map (entry: entry.members = [ config.users.users.default.name ]) [realtime, wireshark]
```

None of those are valid Nix syntax. How do I do the equivalent, without pulling out a new variable?

Comment: Can you do something with the update operator, since `realtime.member = [...]` is (I think) equivalent to `realtime // { member = [...]; }`?

Comment: What counts as a "variable" to you in this context? I'd argue that a let expression defines a locally-scoped constant, not a variable. 

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That's getting rather philosophical, but let's just say a "variable" is any named value, whether it's read-only or not.

Comment: How about making your attrset recursive? Then the name you're referring to is one you would be defining anyhow.

Comment: I don't control the structure of this attrset; it's part of `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language does not support such syntax, because the functionality is already covered by other language features like `let` bindings. Saving a few keystrokes is not worth a complicated language, especially for a language that most people shouldn't need to write very often.

However, you can do this in your specific case:

```hs
users.users.default.extraGroups = ["realtime" "wireshark"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `realtime` and `wireshark` are keys in another attribute set, you can use `builtins.mapAttrs`:

```
let 
  f = (n: v: v // {members = [configure.users.users.default.name]};
in builtins.mapAttrs f yourSet
```

For example,

```
nix-repl> f = n: v: v // {members = [1];}

nix-repl> :p builtins.mapAttrs f { realtime = {}; wireshare = {}; }
{ realtime = { members = [ 1 ]; }; wireshare = { members = [ 1 ]; }; }
```